# SavedStateHandle by Hilt returns null in ViewModel?

Tags: android, viewmodel, dagger-hilt

I use last version of hilt and there is my ViewModel, when onClear() method of my viewModel triggers, saveStateHandle returns null , why ?

```
@HiltViewModel
class CarInfoPickerViewModel @Inject constructor(
private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : AbstractViewModel(){

 fun setVehicleType(type: CarTypesModel) {
    savedStateHandle.set("key", type)
}

private fun getVehicleType(): CarTypesModel? {
    return savedStateHandle.get<TypesModel>("key")
  }
}
```